# SQL Server - Add row for every distict column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, distinct

I need to add a new row with values for every Distinct `ResourceId` in Table. I can get these easily by using query:

```
SELECT Distinct ResourceId FROM [dbo].[Localizations]
```

Now for each of these I need to add a row to the table. Rows are in the format

```
Id       ResourceId             Resourceset    Value             LocaleId
53591    AssessmentType_21      /Assessemnts   Task Format       en
53247    Attr_Description_1     /Description   Concentration     en
53378    Attr_Description_132   /Description   Affirmation       en
```

There can be multiple `LocaleId`s for each `ResourceId`, but I only ever wish to insert one row per `ResourceId`.

The new rows i need to insert will have the format:

- `ResourceId` & `Resourceset` stay the same
- Value will always be `Resourceset`.`ResourceId`
- `LocaleId` will always be `mk`

So for the above example I need to write a query that would insert the following 3 rows to the Table. (Ids for example only)

```
Id       ResourceId             Resourceset     Value                                LocaleId
60001    AssessmentType_21      /Assessemnts    /Assessemnts.AssessmentType_21        mk
60002    Attr_Description_1     /Description    /Description.Attr_Description_1       mk
60003    Attr_Description_132   /Description    /Description.Attr_Description_132     mk
```

Hope this is clear - not the easiest to explain. Did search but nothing similar in questions. Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I underststand correctly:

```
insert into localizations (ResourceId, Resourceset, Value, LocaleId)
    select distinct ResourceId, Resourceset,
           '/' + Resourceset + '.' + ResourceId, 'mk'
    from localizations;
```

This assumes that the pair `ResourceId`/`Resourceset` is unique.

This also assumes that the `id` is assigned automatically (i.e., it is an `identity` column).